# First steps with Python and scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-trees, error-handling

I believe I have a simple if not trivial question. I have a background in statistics and I tend to use Stata and R quite a bit. I am interested in learning Python. I used it for a while now and recently came into contact with [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/).

I am trying to reproduce a simple example.

```
from sklearn import tree
features = [[140, 1],[130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]]
labels = [0 , 0 , 1 , 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print clf.predict([[150, 0]])
```

As you can see, the tiny script tries to predict  - by the means of a decision tree - wether a object with the properties `[150, 0]` is likely a type `1` or `0`.

I run the script and get following error:

```
File "clf_decision_tree.py", line 6
    print clf.predict([[150, 0]])
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I realy don't get what is wrong... Can you help me out? Best /R

PS: I not sure if Cross Validated or Stackoverflow are better places to ask. Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It's also unnecessary to assign the result from fit back onto clf, it is an inplace method which changes your clf object

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: Very useful, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In python 3 the `print` function **must** have parenthesis, so `print(clf.predict([[150, 0]]))` will work

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn import tree

features = [[2200,1], [1500,1], [1800,1], [900,2], [1000,2]]

labels = ['SUV', 'SUV', 'SUV', 'hatchback', 'hatchback']

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf = clf.fit(features, labels)

print(clf.predict([[1350, 1]]))
```